# react-native-maps first person view

Tags: google-maps, react-native, expo, react-native-maps

I am using [react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps) library with expo to render google maps for android and ios. 
At some point, I need to render map in first person view mode, something like this: [image]
I've read react-native-maps documentation and searched github and stackoverflow questions to get an answer but wasn't able to find any.

Can I achieve this using this library?

**EDIT:**

After many research, I've found [#1544](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/pull/1544) which allows us to rotate map, change view angle, etc.

But there is one little problem, functions [animateToBearing](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md) and [animateToViewingAngle](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md) are still working fine, but they are deprecated. And new function [animateCamera](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md) leads me to another [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55317448/attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-double-java-lang-double-doublevalue-on-a-nu)

Comment: Hi David. Did you find a way to solve the first person view mode? Thanks