# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double java.lang.Double.doubleValue()' on a null object reference getDouble

Tags: android, google-maps, react-native, expo, react-native-maps

I am using [react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps) library to show google maps in react-native application. 
I am tracking user movement and want to rotate the map when location will be changed. For map rotation I am calculating rotation angle and using 
[animateCamera](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md) trying to rotate the map like the following:

```
this.map.animateCamera({
    heading: rotation,
    center: {latitude: currentLocation.latitude, longitude: currentLocation.longitude},
    pitch: this.state.currentAngle
}, {duration: 1000});
```

I've checked and `rotation, latitude, longitude, currentAngle` are not `null or empty objects`

But this method throws an error like this: [image]

After this, I tried to use [animateToBearing](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md) method, which is deprecated, as documentation says, but works nicely and rotates the map but shows the deperecation warning.

```
Versions:
    expo: 32.0.0,
    expo-cli: 2.2.0,
    react-native-maps: 0.23.0
```

Any solutions?

P.S. I've searched similar questions on github.com and stackoverflow.com and this question is not duplicated

Comment: It’s probably due to your current location being null at some point.

Comment: no, I checked latitude and longitude values, they are initialized

Comment: I had similar issue with Unity. I added `ndk { abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a' }` to `app/build.gradle` under `defaultConfig` properties. Try it. EDIT: I don't use Expo and I don't know how android code is executed with Expo.